# Django, get fullpath of loaded file

Tags: python, django

/Django 3/ I want to use my loaded file , with external script

to do that I need a full path for this file in my media folder, each time I am loading same file, I get unique name.
example:
`input : image12.jpg  in folder media -> image12_0x982.jpg`

**my model.py:**

```
class InJPG(models.Model):

    file_path = models.FileField(upload_to="media",unique=True)
#I have also prepared forms.py but its simillar as model form
```

**my views.py:**

```
from model import InJPG

def get_name(request):
    file1=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    file2=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    if file1.is_valid():
        file1.save()  
    if file2.is_valid():
        file2.save()

    #print file path:
    file = InJPG.objects.all()
    for f in file:
        print(f.file_name)
    return render(request,'my.html',{'file1':file1,'file2':file2})
```

In this last line (`print(f.file_name)`), I am receiving list of all files with right paths with unique names.

How to get only paths for file1 and file2 ? And open those files using external script?
I want to receive paths of loaded
`file1: /media/image1_0x12.jpg and`
`file2: /media/image2_0x123.jpg.`
Right now I am receiving all images in media folder, and i dont know which one is which

Comment: Explain this please *How to get only paths for file1 and file2 ?*

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you want the filename of uploading file. So, you can do

```
file1_name = file1.file_path.name
file2_name = file2.file_path.name
```

*file_path* in `file1.file_path.name` is the attribute to your class `InJPG`.
See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#using-files-in-models) for more about managing files.

#### Edit

```
from model import InJPG

def get_name(request):
    file1=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    file2=InJPG(request.POST or None)
    if file1.is_valid():
        # Here
        file1_obj = file1.save()  
        file1_name = file1_obj.file_path.name
    if file2.is_valid():
        # Here
        file2_obj = file2.save()
        file2_name = file2_obj.file_path.name
    
    return render(request,'my.html',{'file1': file1,'file2': file2})
```

Comment: i am receiving `AttributeError: InJPG' object has no attribute 'file_name'`. but when i change it to :` file1['file1'].name `, there is no error, but I am receiving: `file`  as a name, its variable name not file

Comment: its same thing. but you are adding it to return render, its affecting template html, where user giving this input. Its different way.
I want to get what user upload (its `'file1':file1`) its form for user. and from this form i want to get what he gives me

Comment: You don't have to loop through all. So, I get rid of loop. More importantly, `saved_file` is stored in `file_obj` to get the data.